# Failded to find lifecycle:common-java8 library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

After I update my Gradle to 6.7.1 and Gradle plugin to 4.2 I decided to build an app with Room,coroutine,dagger-hilt and coroutine's Flow.
I add Libraryies to dependecy and i add plugins id and classpath in build.gradle files even.
then i tried to build my app. but it stops with a error
**THE ERROR: **

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:2.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/common-java8/2.2.0/common-java8-2.2.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/common-java8/2.2.0/common-java8-2.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

**this is my gradle file(build.gradle(project)):**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
ext {
    // App dependencies
    appCompatVersion = "1.2.0"
    constraintLayoutVersion = "2.0.4"
    coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9"
    dataStoreVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    espressoVersion = "3.3.0"
    fragmentVersion = "1.3.0-beta01"
    gradleVersion = "4.1.0"
    hiltAndroidXVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    hiltVersion = "2.28.3-alpha"
    junitVersion = "4.13.1"
    kotlinVersion = "1.4.10"
    ktxVersion = "1.3.2"
    lifecycleVersion = "2.2.0"
    materialVersion = "1.3.0-alpha03"
    navigationVersion = "2.3.1"
    roomVersion = "2.2.5"
    testExtJunitVersion = "1.1.2"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltVersion"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

allprojects {

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}}
```

task clean(type: Delete)

{ delete rootProject.buildDir}

**this is for build.gradle(module):**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.justdoit"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

// Fragment
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion"

// Lifecycle + ViewModel & LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"

// Navigation Component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"

// Coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"

// Dagger Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hiltAndroidXVersion"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltAndroidXVersion"

// DataStore
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$dataStoreVersion"
```

}
kapt {
correctErrorTypes true
}

**Does anyone know why this happened?**  thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are really using arch package and that is not mistake then the version `2.2.0` is incorrect as the latest version of `android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8` is `1.1.1`.

[image]

But if you want to use the `lifecycle-common-java8` of `lifecycle` package then use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8` instead of `android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8` in your build.gradle(app module) dependencies with `2.2.0` version as this version is available.

[image]

You can always verify if you are using some version of google dependencies that is wrong and not available at all to use by referring to this endpoint https://maven.google.com/

Go to the package for which you are getting error and see if the version you used is really the correct one or not.